# Template setting is not saving in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a child theme. I want to override a template of base theme.
I created, `articles-page.php` which starts with:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Articles
*/
```

While creating a page in Wordpress I can see my template listed in the *Page Attributes* widget to my right. The problem is, when I change my template setting to "Articles" and hit update. It still shows `default`. My change is not being saved, hence my template is not being loaded for that page.

Comment: I doubt this is still an open issue, but are you using WooCommerce plugin by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to copy the specific template file you want to alter from the parent theme into the child theme’s directory, then make your changes. The way WordPress works is when it looks for some template file, it looks in the child theme first, then it goes to the parent theme if the file it wants isn’t there.

Copy the file as it is in child theme with same name. Later try editing the template.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. The template I want is not an existing one in parent theme. I'm creating a new template. But unable to apply it to posts.